# send network traffic to from a specific ip and port without using recvfrom or accept

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm new to sockets and network programming so if the question seems dumb, that's because I don't fully understand the above mentioned topics.

Need to continuously send telemetry data over a network. Don't really care who is going to get it, just need to send it out. All the client needs to do is simply to connect to a specific IP and get data from a specific port and the data will be received by it.

My code is written in `C`.

Originally I thought it would be a UDP socket. But it has `recvfrom` method, i.e. I (server) need to wait till someone connects to it. Then I decided to look at TCP/IP socket but this one has an `accept` method.

I looked online for quite some time but didn't find any code that could help me out (maybe I was looking in a wrong place).

Does anyone know if what I'm talking about is possible to do? If so how would I do it? If no, then are there any other ways to do it, i.e. by not using `sockets`?

Comment: The `recvfrom()` method blocks until somebody *sends* to it. There is no connect phase in UDP. From your description the sender *must* send via UDP. Otherwise it would have nothing to send to. So even thinking about TCP is a complete waste of time. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I thought I explained it here: Need to continuously send telemetry data over a network, i.e. all I need to do is to "stream" data from a specific IP and port. Anybody who connects/listens  to this IP and ports should be able to receive "streamed" data. Is this possible?

Comment: You did explain, and part of what you said was wrong, and I corrected it. You have to use UDP and `recvfrom()`.

Comment: @EJP Had to explain it since you said in the first comment that you weren't clear what I was asking.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. You seem to think that `recvfrom()` is unusable. It isn't. It's the answer to your question.

Comment: @EJP I see. I knew it was usable. I was looking for a way to bypass it and do not have a blocking call at all, i.e. just stream data and whoever needs to listen, listens.

Comment: You don't have to bypass it to have a non-blocking call, but why don't you want a blocking call? And `recvfrom()` is for receiving, but you're now talking about sending. Please clarify.

Comment: You can use TCP, listen for connections using `accept`, and send it to the clients that connect. Or you can use UDP and send it to a broadcast address (which will only work within the same network)

Comment: As @immibis implies, do you want to send this data over the Internet?  That piece of information is crucial in deciding how you would implement this.

Comment: @immibis I want to broadcast it within the same network, which would imply that I need to use 255 as my last integer in the IPv4 address, am I correct?

Comment: @immibis Here is what I'm doing on the server side, https://pastebin.com/0R210Peu. On the client side I'm run a netcat, `nc -u 172.24.176.255 5000`. I don't see anything being received. Am I missing something?

Comment: @flashburn "*which would imply that I need to use 255 as my last integer in the IPv4 address, am I correct?*" - not necessarily, it depends on your network's particular subnet mask (what you say is true only for `255.255.255.0`). You need to read up on how subnet masks actually work, and how a subnet's broadcast IP is calculated. If you don't know the exact broadcast IP, you can query your OS for it if one is known to the OS, or you can query the OS for your local IP and subnet mask and then calculate the broadcast IP manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I should have provided more details about my network. Here is partial output from `ifconfig`, `inet addr:172.24.176.219  Bcast:172.24.176.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`. This is the address where I'm broadcasting from.

Comment: @flashburn I figured as much from your other comments.  Your need to `bind()` the server to `172.24.176.219` (or to `0.0.0.0`) and then send packets to `172.24.176.255`. The client needs to bind to its own local `172.24.176.xxx` IP (or to `0.0.0.0`) to read the broadcast packets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Need to continuously send telemetry data over a network. Don't really care who is going to get it, just need to send it out.

Well, your sender need to know WHERE to send data to.

Typically, a receiver would first send a request to your sender so it knows the receiver exists, and then your sender would know where to send packets to.  But, this requires your sender to keep track of all of the receivers so it can send a separate data packet to every receiver individually.  Either UDP or TCP can be used for this.

If you don't want to do things that way, you have 2 other choices:

- **subnet broadcasting** (works with IPv4 only) - your sender can create a UDP socket, then use `setsockopt()` to enable the `SO_BROADCAST` option on it, and then `sendto()` data packets to the broadcast IP address of a given subnet (or use `send()` if it `connect()`'s to the broadcast IP beforehand).  Each packet sent will be automatically delivered to *every* machine that is connected to that same subnet (whether the machines want the packets or not).

  Your receiver can then create and `bind()` a UDP socket to a local network interface that is connected to that same subnet, and then use `recvfrom()` to read the packets (or use `recv()` if it `connect()`'s to the sender's IP address beforehand).
- **multicasting** (works with both IPv4 and IPv6) - your sender can create a UDP socket and then `sendto()` data packets to the IP address of a given multicast group (or use `send()` if it `connect()`'s to the multicast group IP beforehand).  Every packet will be delivered *only* to receivers who have joined the same group.

  Your receiver can create and `bind()` a UDP socket to a local network interface that has a network route to the sender, then use `setsockopt()` to join the socket to the multicast group (using `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` for IPv4, and `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` for IPv6), and then use `recvfrom()` to read the packets (or use `recv()` if it `connect()`'s to the sender's IP beforehand).

> All the client needs to do is simply to connect to a specific IP and get data from a specific port and the data will be received by it.

I would suggest using multicasting for this.  You get the benefits of being able to send fewer packets on the sender side and have them delivered across the network to (potentially) multiple receivers at the same time, and you reduce network overhead by isolating traffic to only the parties who actually want to receive the packets.

Answer (score 1):

> Need to continuously send telemetry data over a network. Don't really care who is going to get it, just need to send it out.

So use UDP.

> All the client needs to do is simply to connect to a specific IP and get data from a specific port and the data will be received by it.

So use UDP. Just call `sendto()` whenever necessary.

> Originally I thought it would be a UDP socket.

You were correct.

> But it has `recvfrom()` method

Correct.

> i.e. I (server) need to wait till someone connects to it.

Incorrect. `recvfrom()` waits until somebody *sends* to it, and the sender doesn't have to wait at all.

> Then I decided to look at TCP/IP socket but this one has an `accept()` method.

Correct. You would have to make your sender a server, use `listen(), accept(), send()`, etc. I don't recommend this for your stated need.

If you want to have multiple listeners, use UDP multicast.