# Sending Ethernet (UDP) Frames to other PCs

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, ethernet

I am trying to send UDP frames from my laptop to another PC as a client-server application using C++. I am monitoring the ethernet port using WireShark and I do not see any information being sent from my laptop. Can someone help regarding this? Am I missing an important step?

```
/*
Simple udp client
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "10.222.14.229"
#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 8888

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];
    char message1[] = "Hello";
    WSADATA wsa;

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //create socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset((char *)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
    while (1)
    { 
        if (sendto(s, message1, strlen(message1), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } 
    memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);   
        puts(buf);
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this thread:

WireShark was missing the Pincap library when it was installed on Windows 10.

Installing the Pincap library solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that code - it runs fine here (apart from the busy loop).  Either:

- the packets aren't going out on the wire, perhaps because there is no route to `10.222.14.229` (try pinging it), or
- WireShark isn't functioning properly (can it see other traffic from your laptop? - it might have a filter set or something)

If you suspect WireShark, you could always try [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=4865).

Comment: I created the busy loop in order to monitor it on WireShark. I will first try MNM and will update accordingly.

Comment: @PaulSanders You have failed to ask the right questions. Voted down.

Comment: OK, LMK.  I need an upvote now because @EJP thinks he needs to [get back at me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731644/send-network-traffic-to-from-a-specific-ip-and-port-without-using-recvfrom-or-ac/50732123#comment88519057_50732123) :)

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm merely trying to stimulate you into explaining your bizarre behaviour of downvoting answers as though they were questions.

Comment: @EJP Well that's not the way to do it.  You can just ask me.  I commented on the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731644/send-network-traffic-to-from-a-specific-ip-and-port-without-using-recvfrom-or-ac/50732123#comment88519057_50732123).

Comment: I did ask you and nothing happened for days.

Comment: @EJP Do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731644/send-network-traffic-to-from-a-specific-ip-and-port-without-using-recvfrom-or-ac/50732123#comment88502919_50732123)?  That is not a question and you posted it _yesterday_, not 'days ago'.  I did see it but I ignored it - because it is not a question.  I think we are both becoming less confrontational now, which is good. 
It's half six in the morning here ferchristssake, I'm barely awake!

Comment: The problem was WireShark. It was missing some libraries in order to monitor the ethernet port.

Comment: @ayo OK, cool, thanks for posting back.  If you think that the tricks you used to get WireShark to work properly are worth sharing you could post your own answer.  Future visitors to this page might find that helpful, and you might even get some upvotes :) (You'd get one from me.)